# How to change the position and size of Tooltip in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, desktop

I am on Windows 10 Pro, 19042.1348. When I hover my mouse over any element, the tooltip shown is very small, moreover, it is under the cursor, hidden by it. Please see the image attached, in some cases, it is very worst when the text length is below 6. Fully covered by the cursor. I tried to change the location (x,y) of the tooltip and the font size, in windows settings. but I could not find it. Any ideas, How to do this either in settings or Regedit?
[image]

Comment: Tooltip `x,y` will be backed into the `.exe` or `.dll`'s of the compiled application. It's unlikely you'll be able to change them or add an offset via the registry. Out of interest, which application is that in your screenshot?

Comment: @spikey_richie  It is adobe photoshop 2020.